# Amplify API - Cannot return null for non-nullable field Model._version

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I thought that the _version field should auto create when we create a record using graphql api, but when I am trying to fetch the record after creating it is getting fetched with no problem but when I am trying to list the record with _version field it is giving me error.

`"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field MyModel._version.",`